# Golang swaggo rendering error: "Failed to load API definition" and "Fetch error doc.json"

Tags: go, swagger

I am running a Golang HTTP server with Gin and using `swaggo` for generating Swagger API documentation.

After generating my documentation using `swag init` and registering it with `r.GET("/swagger/*any", ginSwagger.WrapHandler(swaggerFiles.Handler))`, I get the following error when accessing the Swagger UI at `http://localhost:3000/swagger/index.html`:

[image: image of swagger ui error]

```
Errors
Fetch error
Internal Server Error doc.json
```

The browser network console and Gin logs just shows an error 500 for the `/swagger/doc.json` call, so it's unclear if I'm missing some configuration?

```
[GIN] 2024/03/13 - 18:10:45 | 200 |     745.709µs |             ::1 | GET      "/swagger/index.html"
[GIN] 2024/03/13 - 18:10:45 | 200 |     240.583µs |             ::1 | GET      "/swagger/swagger-ui.css"
[GIN] 2024/03/13 - 18:10:45 | 200 |    1.802584ms |             ::1 | GET      "/swagger/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"
[GIN] 2024/03/13 - 18:10:45 | 200 |    2.035208ms |             ::1 | GET      "/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js"
[GIN] 2024/03/13 - 18:10:45 | 200 |     166.958µs |             ::1 | GET      "/swagger/swagger-ui.css.map"
[GIN] 2024/03/13 - 18:10:45 | 200 |    5.479542ms |             ::1 | GET      "/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js.map"
[GIN] 2024/03/13 - 18:10:45 | 200 |     242.625µs |             ::1 | GET      "/swagger/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js.map"
[GIN] 2024/03/13 - 18:10:45 | 500 |      19.375µs |             ::1 | GET      "/swagger/doc.json"
[GIN] 2024/03/13 - 18:10:45 | 200 |     163.541µs |             ::1 | GET      "/swagger/favicon-32x32.png"
```

Environment:

```
swagger version: 2.0.0
go version: 1.6.*
OS: Mac
```

Comment: In most cases, the problem is that you forgot to import the generated docs as `_ "<your-project-package>/docs"`